# Python class design for inheritance with varied number of inherited methods

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am building a Python API wrapper for a SOAP API.  I need to design a set of API classes which contain a varied number of verb actions (`add`, `get`, `list`, `remove` etc.).  Additionally, because of the nature of the objects in the SOAP API, these may also contain additional methods from a subset of (`sync`, `options`, `apply`, `restart` and `reset`).  Internals of each verb means that very few cases require overriding and can easily be inherited.  My problem is that some endpoints are singletons, or for whatever reason may only support a subset of these methods.  Meaning that:

EndpointA

- `get` only

EndpointB

- `add`, `get`, `list`, `remove`
- `apply` and `restart`

EndpointC

- `add` and `get` only

EndpointD

- `add`, `get`, `list`, `remove`
- `apply`, `restart`, `reset`

I have more than 100 endpoints.  Most fit a common theme of:

- `add`, `get`, `list`, `remove`

There are, however, many exceptions.

In my current design, all endpoints instantiate with `Client` attribute that controls the SOAP connection, requests and responses on the wire.  I am looking for an approach to flexibly create a class design allowing me to drop in methods without needing to duplicate code or inadvertently inherit methods that an API endpoint doesn't support.

A flat inheritance is problematic as I don't have enough flexibility for all the permutations for methods.

```
BaseAPI(object):

    def __init___(self, client):
        self.client = client


ChildAPI(BaseAPI):

    def __init___(self, client):
        super().__init__(client)

    def get(self, **kwargs):
        soap_method = methodcaller("".join(["get", self.__class__.__name__]), **kwargs)
        resp = soap_method(self.client.service)
        return resp

    def list(self, **kwargs):
        soap_method = methodcaller("".join(["list", self.__class__.__name__]), **kwargs)
        resp = soap_method(self.client.service)
        return stuff

    # same for add and remove...


EndpointA(BaseAPI):

    def __init___(self, client):
        super().__init__(client)

    # now i have a problem as i only wanted the get method...


EndpointD(BaseAPI):

    def __init___(self, client):
        super().__init__(client)

    # I have all the methods I wanted...
```

I was thinking about mixins, but as you can see, the verb methods are dependent on the common client.  From my understanding, mixins should only inherit from `object`.

Can anyone suggest how to lay out my class design to promote re-use as far as possible, and avoid a lack of flexibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand it right that the method's implementation, if the Endpoints support it, are all the same for all Endpoints? In this case, you could solve it with a little list that holds the supported methods names and gets overwritten by every Endpoint subclass:

```
import functools

class BaseAPI:
    def __init___(self, client):
        self.client = client

class ChildAPI(BaseAPI):
    supported_methods = ["add", "get", "list", "remove", "apply", "restart", "reset"]

    @classmethod
    def assert_supported(cls, func):
        """Decorator looks up func's name in self.supported_methods."""
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if func.__name__ not in self.supported_methods:
                raise AttributeError("This Endpoint does not support this method.")
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    # implementation of methods here, each decorated with @assert_supported
    @assert_supported
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        soap_method = methodcaller("".join(["get", self.__class__.__name__]), **kwargs)
        resp = soap_method(self.client.service)
        return resp

    @assert_supported
    def list(self, **kwargs):
        soap_method = methodcaller("".join(["list", self.__class__.__name__]), **kwargs)
        resp = soap_method(self.client.service)
        return stuff

class EndpointA(BaseAPI):
    supported_methods = ["get"]

class EndpointB(BaseAPI):
    supported_methods = ["add", "get", "list", "remove", "apply", "restart"]

class EndpointC(BaseAPI):
    supported_methods = ["add", "get"]

class EndpointD(BaseAPI):
    pass   # no change to supported_methods => all of them
```

This reduces the effort for the adaption of the base methods to one single line per class, and still gives you the flexibility to add whatever code necessary.

Comment: This looks like the most feasible way to support this.  The only downside I can see is the methods appearing to be available from the IDE, but its a small price to pay.  Keen to test this out.

Comment: @1: True. You can still put "_" in front of the name, which should hide the `_supported_methods` in most auto-completion scenarios at first. @2: Both is possible, but I'd personallly prefer to keep the decorator function directly where it's supposed to be used, which is only in this class, since it strongly depends on the `supported_methods` attribute of this class.

Comment: yeah, i would hide with `_supported_methods`, but i meant more about `add` coming up in autocomplete, when not supported for the endpoint.  Again, compared to where I am now, this is a nice problem to have...  The proposed solution is great for me.

Comment: All I'm left with is a corner case where a few endpoints require methods which don't conform to the base method signature, so overriding is actually an overload, which violates LSP.  I'm considering just extending `BaseAPI` for these.  I'm not sure how better to handle this in Python.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, I confused "methods" with the "supported_methods" attribute. I was thinking of a different decorator which would remove the method from the class if not supported, but the decorator can't access the class. Or at least I didn't get it to work.
Hm LSP... I confess I had to google that :D But if you really need it, maybe there's a way you can make your overload only be additional keyword args in the signature?

Comment: IDE is giving me an `object not callable` for the wrapper function return...  changing parent method sig to `assert_supported(self, func)` resolves this

Comment: OK, I fixed this with an edit and added @classmethod as this provided the ability for decorator inheritance which I've used in my implementation